# VS Intellisense: Show INDENTED multiline code example on hover-over

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, xml-documentation

Is such a thing possible?  If it's not clear what I'm talking about, here's a detailed example:

Take this quick utility class I wrote a few weeks ago (details omitted), along with the example I want to share:

```
public abstract class CommonOdinAttributesForOwnedType<TProperty, TParent> : OdinAttributeProcessor<TProperty>
{
    //snip
}

//EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION (Recommended to be nested inside MyBaseType):
protected class BoolAttributesInsideMyBaseType : CommonOdinAttributesForOwnedType<bool, MyBaseType>
{
    protected override List<Attribute> GetAdditionalAttributes()
    {
        return new List<Attribute>()
        {
            new ToggleLeftAttribute(), //add more desired attributes here
        };
    }
}
```

I have the following XML above the abstract class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gives ALL objects of type TProperty drawn within classes derived from TParent a requested list of 
/// Odin GUI attributes
/// <code>
/// //EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION (Recommended to be nested inside MyBaseType):
/// protected class BoolAttributesInsideMyBaseType : CommonOdinAttributesForOwnedType&lt;bool, MyBaseType&gt;
/// {
///     protected override List&lt;Attribute&gt; GetAdditionalAttributes()
///     {
///         return new List&lt;Attribute&gt;()
///         {
///             new ToggleLeftAttribute(), //add more desired attributes here
///         };
///     }
/// }
/// </code>
/// </summary>
```

Now, I could have SWORN that when I originally created the class, the tooltip looked like I wanted ... but maybe I'm hallucinating.  At any rate, during this week's refactor (during which the file was moved/renamed and fed through ReSharper's cleanup), I noticed that the Intellisense tooltip now looks like hot garbage:

[image: Intellisense with zero whitespace control]

Adding `<br/>` to the end of each line only helps a little:

[image]

...and I haven't been able to find a way to manually specify indentation the way `<br/>` specifies new lines.  I've also tried many combinations of `<remarks>`, `<example>`, `<para>`, and various ways to nest the blocks, but nothing worked.

So: Is there any way to (ideally) get Visual Studio 2019 to actually parse whitespace found inside an XML documentation `<code></code>` block, or (barring that) use some other block that manually adds indentation, the way I've manually added new lines with `<br/>`?  I've looked and looked, and can't find a way to do either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth - I have been able to indent source code in XML documentation (at least on VS 2022), by copy/pasting Unicode character u2800 (the Braille pattern blank character).

I have not tried in other versions of Visual Studio. **Unfortunately, the width of the blank character is not the same width as the rest of the monospaced characters** (at least with the font I normally use, which is Office CodePro Light), so you can't rely on this character to create nice looking ascii-block diagrams that look right on both the editor as well as on the  hover-over Intellisense view)

For convenience, the character can be copied here (between the single quotes):

```
'⠀'
```

[image]

Comment: Close enough! Accepting this as the new answer.

FWIW, it also works on VS 2019.

Comment: This is a clever solution.  Keep in mind that this works for Intellisense, but will probably be wonky if you actually generate XML documentation.  But, does anyone actually do that anymore anyway?

Comment: As of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8, this hack is no longer necessary. Regular spaces will be rendered as whitespace in the hover-over.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I think I found the *proper* way to format code in documentation using simple spaces. The trick is in using the following XML structure:

```
/// <remarks>
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// private async Task SomeOperationAsync() {
///     // this will be properly indented
///     await DoAsync();
/// }
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// </remarks>
```

EDIT: This seems to have been introduced in an update to Visual Studio 2022 (probably v. 17.1) On my Visual Studio 2019 (last update was 16.11.6) it does not work.

Comment: I'm leaving your other answer as accepted because it still works with 2019, but this is fantastic. I may have to upgrade VS soon, after all...

Answer (score 3):

> VS Intellisense: Show INDENTED multiline code example on hover-over

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want.**

**Actually**, vs xml document does not have the ability to keep code-style format.

Under the [summary xml node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#summary), it cannot keep the code format. You have to manually change the format. Use some codes to change the style as it shows.

> Is there any way to (ideally) get Visual Studio 2019 to actually parse
> whitespace found inside an XML documentation `<code></code>` block

**Line break** can use `<br/>` or `<para/>`. **But** there is no way to indent the first line. Html formatting methods, spacing, spaces, etc. do not work.

**In fact**, this is a flaw---xml document of vs does not have the ability to indent the line and keep the code style.

**So far, we can only do what you have done.**

**Besides**, if you still want the feature, you could `suggest a feature` on [our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and the Team will consider your question carefully and I hope they will give you a  satisfactory reply.

Comment: Thank you.  I've done as you suggested and [requested a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1133060/add-additional-whitespace-formatting-options-space.html).